# Yii2 Cannot insert/update more than 1000 checked rows

Tags: php, post, yii2

I am trying to insert/update more than 1000 selected/ checked rows and when I submit (POST) form my controller inserts/ updates the first 999 checked rows. I used var_dump($_POST) and it returns the first 999 rows. Any help Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue happen since you are execute the maximum post size, so that you need to change default value from `8M` to `1024M` -for test- and you can do this by:

1) PHP.ini: `post_max_size="8M"`

OR

2) .htaccess: `php_value post_max_size 8M` (Note: this will be work if server accept override.

Note: You need to restart server after update php.ini